# mysql: get top answer

Tags: mysql

I have a table called ***answers*** with 2 rows:

**questionid - answer**

as you can probably guess *questionid* stores the question id number and *answer* stores the answer, the answers are just numbers 1 to 8

I want to display the top answer.

**eg:**

questionid - answer

```
4 - 7
4 - 3
4 - 3
2 - 3
6 - 7
7 - 1
9 - 8
1 - 5
```

top answer = 3

i've tried:

```
SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE questionid='$qid' ORDER BY answer DESC LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT answer FROM answers WHERE questionid='$qid' ORDER BY answer DESC LIMIT 1
```

*$qid = page id ie: /question.php?qid=4*

but both return incorrect.

**Update:**

Is there away of showing the result without using:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// stuff here
}
```

as I just want to show 1 result (ie the top answer) based on $qid

Comment: I think you mean that it has two *columns*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this (`HAVING()`, `WHERE`, `MAX()`, etc) The commonality is [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

```
SELECT answer, COUNT(answer) FROM questions GROUP BY answer ORDER BY COUNT(answer) DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will return:

```
3 - 3
```

Read more [about `GROUP BY`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php/).

#### UPDATE

Seems you modified your question after I posted this answer.

If you want to limit the query to a specific question, add a `WHERE` clause as the other questions.

```
... FROM questions WHERE questionid = X GROUP BY ...
```

**Note:** Be mindful of [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

When you only have 1 record, you can forego the `while` loop and just access the top result.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

**Note:** You'll like want to do more error checking (e.g. ensure a *result* was returned). Also, don't use `mysql_*` functions as they are [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 8 minutes" will be back in 8 mins, thank you Jason. Yes I was looking at MAX() and COUNT() before I wrote my question but couldn't get my head around it :(

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) AS answer_count, answer FROM answers WHERE questionid='$qid' GROUP BY answer ORDER BY answer_count DESC LIMIT 1
```